# in vim with xclip, yank to clipboard

Tags: vim

I have vim 7.2 (-clipboard -xterm_clipboard ...) in Ubuntu. You can see that it's not support clipboard. So I want to write little vim script which copies visual selected text into the clipboard using xclip tool.

You know xclip tool works like that:

```
echo 'hello' | xclip -selection clipboard      #it copies 'hello' into clipboard
```

And vim can run shell commands, so I want to copy visual selected text to where instead of 'hello', But I don't know how to combine xclip and vim. Can you help me to implement it.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Are you using your distribution-provided `vim`?  If so, the `vim-tiny`, `vim`, and `vim-nox` packages have no clipboard support, but it does exist in `vim-lesstiff`, `vim-gtk`, and `vim-gnome`.

If you insist on doing it your way,

```
:'<,'>w !xclip
```

would send the current selected lines to xclip, and

```
:call system('xclip', @0)
```

would send the last yank to xclip.

Comment: +1 for pointing out what might be the real problem (using the wrong package) in addition to the answer

Comment: yeah, I'm using distribution-provided vim in Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: thanks ephemient, I tryid like that: ":'<,'>w !xclip -selection clipboard" as you said, it copies whole line into clipboard, how to copy just visual selected text not whole line?

Comment: @Nyambaa: Try switching to the distribution-provided `vim-gnome` or yanking first.  Handling character-wise, line-wise, and block-wise selections in vimscript is nontrivial.

Comment: I had to make visual selection, type `:w !xclip -selection clipboard`.

Comment: Is there a way to make `gx` pass what's under the cursor to `xclip`?

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for that kind of solution since I first tried to switch to vim-gtk but it was having trouble handling enormous log files. Maybe a better solution for me is compiling it just adding +clipboard support

Comment: The other comment here mentioned "make visual selection, type `:w !xclip -selection clipboard`" which works but is too long to type. The default behavior of `w !xclip` actually works, and you just need to paste the content by clicking BOTH left and right mouse bottoms simultaneously.

Answer (score 5):

For me, Vim stopped being able to copy to the `*` and `+` registers over SSH, even though `:echo has('clipboard')` was `1`, and other X programs still worked. The solution for me was to add a mapping that yanks (via a register) to xclip:

```
vnoremap <silent><Leader>y "yy <Bar> :call system('xclip', @y)<CR>
```

I select text, hit `\y` and it arrives on my local clipboard. You can change which register it uses, e.g. `c` for "clipboard" with `"cy` and `@c`.

Comment: Crazy thing that happens here: after doing that, I can `middle-click` to paste the yanked lines on my local computer, but it will take a while. It seems the actual fetching of the content happens at the time I click to paste, not at the time I yank.

It happens that also when middle-clicking for other reasons, like closing browser tabs, also takes a while. This can be solved by just selecting other text after you're done with the remote clipboard contents.

Comment: A `:vmap` command shows `v  ,y          * "yy | :call system('xclip', @y)<CR>`. Clipboard contents are not affected. EDIT: If I change `'xclip'` to `'xclip -sel clipboard'`, it works as expected.