# Cannot install vim ubuntu 13.10

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, vim

I am fairly new to Linux and vim so please have this in mind.

A couple of days ago I compiled vim with python support largely using the method mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10103947 (in particular: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g)

Everything was working alright, I even started getting to know my .vimrc and various options, but I realized that apparently I had not compiled vim with +clipboard (and +xterm_clipboard?). Since I wanted to be able to copy/paste text between vim and external applications, I decided to re-install it. I proceeded to delete all folders/files in my home folder (where I installed it in the first place), associated with vim (I fear that at this step something must have gone wrong) to prepare for the new installation.

This time, when compiling, I used the first method mentioned above (making sure that X is included and all other clipboard-related things), but once I finished with the whole procedure and did a vim --version nothing happened, as if it was not installed at all. I tried the method in the youtube video (which is pretty much identical and was working up until now) too, but again to no avail.

I think that I must have deleted some important file/configuration, but cannot be sure. Do you have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to run this single command in your terminal to get a working Vim with clipboard support built-in:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually ended up doing that anyway (it also includes python support). Still I am not sure why the other way didn't work.