# Can't use register +

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-14.04

**TL;DR**

When I copy some text from an external application, and then in vim I do `"+p`, it tells me `E353: Nothing in register "` instead of copying this text.

**More details**

I used to work with vim on an Ubuntu-13.10, and it worked fine. I recently changed of computer, and installed Ubuntu-14.10

Now, I can't use vim `+` register, neither to copy, nor to paste from an other application.

What can explain this behavior, and how can I fix it?

**Some more practical details**

- I use Gnome terminal
- I can still pass in insert mode and press `Shift + Insert` to paste something copied from another application
- When I ssh, from this computer, to another one with an Ubuntu-14.04 server, I don't have any issue with this register

Comment: Are you sure you installed vim which has X support? You can check by `vim --version | grep xterm_clipboard` and `vim --version | grep X11`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101488/cut-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim-on-ubuntu

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome` will likely solve your problem.

Comment: installing `vim-gnome` solved my issue! Thanks for all your suggestions. @romainl: feel free to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is the case on *every* UNIX-derived system, Ubuntu's default Vim is a lightweight  version (`vim-tiny` IIRC) that is *not* built with clipboard support.

Installing the `vim-gnome` package gives you clipboard support as well as other useful features:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: What is the CentOS equivalent of vim-gnome? I'm working on a remote server, which doesn't have the xterm_clipboard feature for the vim installed

Comment: 1. You are not looking for the `xterm_clipboard` feature, but for the `clipboard` feature. 2. The equivalent of `vim-gnome` on CentOS is `vim-X11`.