# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Can't enable xterm_clipboard in VIM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-16.04

I use VIM a lot, and have previously been able to get `+xterm_clipboard` [support working by using a script provided in a separate post on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101488/cut-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim-on-ubuntu) I've re-installed Ubuntu on my machine, and have since migrated from Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (Wily) to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial).

```
# Get the compile-dependencies of vim
sudo apt-get build-dep vim
# If you haven't got mercurial, get it
sudo apt-get install mercurial
# Get the source
hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim_source
# Compile it
cd vim_source
./configure \
    --enable-perlinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-pythoninterp=dynamic \
    --enable-rubyinterp=dynamic \
    --enable-cscope \
    --enable-gui=auto \
    --enable-gtk2-check \
    --enable-gnome-check \
    --with-features=huge \
    --with-x \
    --with-compiledby="Your Name <youremail@domain.com>" \
    --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config
make && sudo make install
```

However, this no longer works, and I can't make use of <kbd>"</kbd>,<kbd>+</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd> to yank buffers to the system clipboard. I don't see anything obvious in the `.configure` output, but `vim --version` always shows `-xterm_clipboard` when I build it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You should have noticed that the source is no longer hosted on Google code via mercurial (`hg`) anymore, and has migrated to GitHub in the error messages generated by the provided script.

You'll need to use the new source tree, `git`, and some developer libraries will need to be installed in advance.

## Code Listing (Updated for Ubuntu 18.04 and onward)

---

```
# Get the compile-dependencies of vim
sudo apt-get -y build-dep vim
# Install the "checkinstall" tool so the "make install" step is
# wrapped and the result is a .deb file that can be removed later by
# your package manager rather than having to hunt down every file deployed
# by "make install", which might not be possible if it overwrites existing
# system files.
sudo apt-get -y install checkinstall
# Install python dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3-dev
# Install xorg dev
sudo apt-get -y install xorg-dev
# Install git
sudo apt-get -y install git
# Get the source
git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git vim_source
# Remove ./configure cache in case we have to run this twice due to permissions
# related issues.
rm vim_source/src/auto/config.cache
# Compile it
cd vim_source
make clean distclean
./configure \
    --enable-perlinterp=yes \
    --enable-python3interp=yes \
    --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
    --with-python3-command=python3.6 \
    --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3.6-config --configdir) \
    --enable-cscope \
    --enable-gui=auto \
    --enable-gtk2-check \
    --enable-gnome-check \
    --with-features=huge \
    --with-x \
    --with-compiledby="DevNull <darkstar@/dev/null>"
# Build quickly (parallel jobs).
make -j$(nproc)
# Need root to install
sudo checkinstall
```