# xsel/xclip on headless SSH server for vim/tmux

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ssh, cygwin, tmux

Is there a way to enable `xclip`/`xsel` on a headless SSH server? I'm working with a machine that formerly ran Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, and has been migrated to Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have various `vim` and `tmux` configurations to increase productivity when I login to the server via `ssh`. However, now that it's headless and running a server OS, a lot of my clipboard functionality is broken:

- `"+y` no longer works in `vim` ([which we recompiled with `xterm_clipboard` support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37079424/ubuntu-16-04-lts-cant-enable-xterm-clipboard-in-vim)), so I've lost a convenient way to copy `vim` buffers between `tmux` windows on the remote machine.
- `tmux` copy/paste works fine, which is odd, given that my "yank" command is:

  - `bind     -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"` (this worked even with `xclip` not even installed; guess it fell back to default behavior).
- `cygwin` no longer seems to acquire a copy of clipboard data when x11forwarding is enabled via `ssh -X hostname`.

Is there a way to get this working from a "cygwin on windows" to "ubuntu 16.04.3 headless server" setup? I'd even install `xorg` if necessary, if it just sat quietly in the background and allowed the clipboard to work again.

Comment: Related Posts: [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/84/778) & [How can I copy over an ssh session without +clipboard?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/8354/778). Related article using `netcat`: [Exposing your clipboard over SSH](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/8259104) and [what I use](https://gist.github.com/PeterRincker/8fab6296b6905793e284e84aba7041bc) with this technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, install the vim-gtk package. It comes with the necessary dependencies for clipboard to work through X Forwarding.

Comment: Is this an option I could just pass to vim and recompile? Or does vim-gtk come with some additional libraries/tools/features? I'd like to use my local build of vim.

Comment: You need Vim compiled with clipboard support on both ends to benefit from X forwarding.

Comment: I've just tried rebuilding VIM like this, ssh'ing into the headless server, starting tmux, then opening vim in multiple tmux windows: none of the vim instances can paste to each other using `"+y`/`"+p`: they can only share via the tmux paste buffers. Each vim instance can copy/paste to itself using that buffer though.

Comment: Was forgetting to use "ssh -Y" afterwards.