# I can't paste what I copied to the clipboard with Vim on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, clipboard

I tried yank to clipboard from vim.
But it does not do it.
I've attempted with <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> (also, I tried <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>)after select copy area in Visual Mode.
But does not paste copied content when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> typed on terminal.

Why it does not paste in terminal despite I yanked to special register?
`clipboard` and `xterm_clipboard`  features are enabled in my vim.

I using

- Vim 8.1 patch 1-320
- Ubuntu 19.04
- Virtualbox 6.0.12

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q seems  more appropriate to https://superuser.com OR https://vim.stackexchange.com  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Do you run XWindows? Is `vim` compiled with X11 libraries (+X11)?

Comment: Yes X11 is enabled in my Vim

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't know if it helps, but using synaptics, the problem seemed to disappear, but using libinput, problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has 2 clipboards. [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/7431860), using `"*yy` or `"+yy` (one or the other) should yank text to and from your ctrl+c / ctrl+v clipboard. (This works on X11 systems, which you have, according to the comments.)

[Also](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) [see](https://askubuntu.com/questions/347519/unable-to-copy-from-vim-to-system-clipboard) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101488/cut-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim-on-ubuntu).

Comment: I use vim-gnome in ubuntu, but "*yy and "+yy" both doesn't work.

Comment: What's the output of `:echo has('clipboard')`? If it's `0`, you don't have a version of vim installed that can use `+clipboard`, and may want to consider installing a different version.

Comment: result is 1 and +clipboard

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it paste content to other areas (like a word processor) and / or can you paste into the terminal by middle-clicking?

Comment: copy from: other application
paste to: vim
is works.

but,
copy from vim paste to other application doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to paste with `"*p` or `"+p`, or are you doing so with ctrl shift v?

Comment: Not sure what could be causing the issue, unless you've bound one of the other characters to something else or you're on a remote connection.

Comment: there is no these setting in my vim.